# Create Simple Listener for Link Clicks

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events, extjs6

I have a fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/v6s).

Still trying to figure out Ext JS. How do I fire a click event when a link is clicked? Should be the simplest thing in the world right? The alert should appear when clicking the `a` obviously but not the `span`. Also, I want to move that chunk of code that attaches the listener into a `ViewController` if possible.

```
var container = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    html: '<div><a class="test">test....</a><br><br><br><span>some text</span></div>',
    listeners: {
        click: function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert('I have been clicked!')  
        }
    }
});


container.down('a.test').on('click', function(){ 
    this.fireEvent('click', container); 
}, container);
```

I was trying to follow the [instructions here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/events.html) in the "Listening for DOM Events" section.

Also, once my handler function returns, I don't want any other handlers to potentially fire.. so I guess the equivalent of jQuery `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `listeners` too, like:

```
listeners: {
    click: {
        element: 'el',
        delegate: 'a',
        fn: function() {
            Ext.Msg.alert('I have been clicked!')
        }
    }
}
```

A working example based on yours: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/v72

(The `delegate` can be any selector)

Comment: Ah, this is much better. Is it possible to add a second click listener [like this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/v74) though? It seems to overwrite the first one.

Comment: You can remove the `delegate` property and in your handler function decide according to the `e.target` element what to do.. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/v76

Comment: ok that's what i figured, checking the `target` with if-conditions. not ideal but it works. thx

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

You need to use `getEl()` in your listener to retrieve the actual DOM element, in order attach the listener to it.

```
container.getEl().down('a.test').on('click', function(){ 
this.fireEvent('click', container); 
    }, container);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so where do I put that code in the real app though? `ViewController`, `View`, ...? I mean the snippet that attaches the listener. This is all very verbose.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, I'm new to ExtJS myself